# Converting svg-file into base64 into json with NodeRed

Tags: json, svg, base64, mqtt, node-red

I try to convert a svg-file first into base64 and then into a JSON object on node red to send it via mqtt to another flow. The svg-file was made on a raspberry pi and is generated by a script within an execution-Node. So I like to know, which further nodes and code I need to convert the svg-file first into a base64 and then into a JSON object.

Comment: SVG is an XML variant - why convert it to Base64, then JSON?

Comment: as @theGleep says this conversion doesn't make much sense at the moment. But all the nodes needed to do this are available, so up date the question with details of what you have already tried.